# SAS SQL JOIN increase rows instead of match rows

Tags: sql, join, sas

I have a problem with full outer join in SAS
I want to join two database. 
A is the "mama" containing patient ID,SEX,RACE,blablabla...but dont have the status variable.
B is the one only containing ID and status.
So A is actually a way bigger database than B and what I'm going to do is to put B including status into A. Here's my code:

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE C AS
select *
from A full outer join B
on A.id=B.id ;
RUN;
```

The result I got is actually not merging two database. Instead, I got the database C, which all the data from A on the top(status variable is null), and then the data B following by A (status variable is there but all other variables are showing Null). Thus, what i did is just adding rows....

Here is some conditions on my codes;
1. I use the University Edition
2. the format of ID is actually Char. Since B's ID (example:BD123), I convert numeric variable ID from A into char variable .

Anybody could help me with this? Thank you very much :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you got an entire concatenation (100 rows in A, 15 rows in B, 115 in C) then you likely didn't correctly match the ID variable format when you converted.  You may have an issue with additional spaces or something to that effect (the length of `B.id` may not match `A.id`).  If possible I would convert the ID to numeric, or do a more careful conversion to character.

Second, if you're intending to just get the number of rows of A back (just adding B information to A), then you want a `left join` not a `full outer join`.

Comment: Hey Joe, Thank you for your reply. This is a little more complicated than I originally thought 0.0. The reason why ID is Char bc there's another column called sample_ID and ppl in my group mix sample_ID with ID together..I guess I need to separate them first...

Answer (score 0):

I Think you might be looking at left join instead.

```
proc sql;
   create table C as 
   select A.*, B.* 
   from A left join B 
   on A.ID=B.ID;
quit;
```